# Values are not getting matched while using php with oracle

Tags: php, oracle

So i have just started working on PHP with Oracle and I am getting values from user using select option as you can see in HTML file, however when i apply where condition on 'Job', it wouldn't match the values.  I have also used 'upper' with where condition to avoid case-sensitivity but it wouldn't work. On the contrary when i apply where condition on 'deptno', it works fine.
Is there anything I am missing?

```
<html>
    <body>
        
        
        <form action="emp_info.php" method="POST">
            <b>Job:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</b>                     
            <select name="Employee" id="Employee">
                <option value="CLERK">CLERK</option>
                <option value="SALESMAN">SALESMAN</option>
                <option value="MANAGER">MANAGER</option>
                <option value="ANALYST">ANALYST</option>
                <option value="PRESIDENT">PRESIDENT</option>
              </select>
              <br>
              <br>
              <b>Department Number:</b>                     
              <select name="Department" id="Department">
                  <option value="10">ten</option>
                  <option value="20">20</option>
                  <option value="30">30</option>
                </select>
              <br>
              <br>
                <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

emp_info.php

```
<?php

   $db_sid = 
   "(DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = DESKTOP-KFR5A5D)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )";            // Your oracle SID, can be found in tnsnames.ora  ((oraclebase)\app\Your_username\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\NETWORK\ADMIN) 
  
   $db_user = "scott";   // Oracle username e.g "scott"
   $db_pass = "tiger1234";    // Password for user e.g "1234"
   $deptno1=$_POST['Department'];
   $job1=$_POST['Employee'];
   echo $job1;
   $con = oci_connect($db_user,$db_pass,$db_sid); 
   if($con) 
      { echo "Oracle Connection Successful."; } 
   else 
      { die('Could not connect to Oracle: '); } 
      

     $q = "select empno,ename,job, mgr, to_char(hiredate,'dd/mm/yyyy') hiredate, sal, comm, deptno".
     " from emp".
     " where job=$job1";
     $query_id3 = oci_parse($con, $q);
     $runselect = oci_execute($query_id3); 
     

     while($row = oci_fetch_array($query_id3, OCI_BOTH+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) 
     {
     
     echo "<br>".$row["JOB"]."<br>";
     $empno = $row["EMPNO"];
     $ename = $row["ENAME"];
     $job = $row["JOB"];
     $mgr = $row["MGR"];
     $hiredate = $row["HIREDATE"];
     $sal = $row["SAL"];
     $comm = $row["COMM"];
     $deptno = $row["DEPTNO"];

   } 

?>
```

Comment: Is that your actual DB password? If it is, you should edit it out ASAP!

Comment: You can print `$q` and check what is the query. You can also share that here for further help

Comment: @Take-Some-Bytes Thanks for telling but i am using oracle locally, so it won't make any difference. But still i changed the password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need single quotes to be in the SQL string around the value.  But before doing that, read the back half of [The Underground PHP and Oracle Manual](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/php/underground-php-oracle-manual-098250.html) and do things like use bind variables (for security and performance) instead of doing `" where job=$job1"`.  Also check the examples on https://php.net/manual/en/ref.oci8.php  (Finally, consider using a [NOW doc](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/php-53-quotnowdocsquot-make-sql-escaping-easier) for SQL).

Comment: Thanks alot for the help. You saved my day